# Setting Undertow log level via logback

Tags: java, logging, undertow

I am using undertow as an embedded rest server in a project.
This project uses logback for logging.
What I would like to do is to configure ALL of Undertow's logging via my logback configuration.

I know that I can enable sl4fj by passing a system property like thus:

```
System.setProperty("org.jboss.logging.provider", "slf4j"
```

However, it doesn't look to configure all of Undertow's logging.
For example, I always see a RuntimeException printed if I set http status code to 501 on the HttpServerExchange object in a handler.

This exception comes from HttpServerExchange setStatusCode(...) method.

```
public HttpServerExchange setStatusCode(final int statusCode) {
    if (statusCode < 0 || statusCode > 999) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid response code");
    }
    int oldVal = state;
    if (allAreSet(oldVal, FLAG_RESPONSE_SENT)) {
        throw UndertowMessages.MESSAGES.responseAlreadyStarted();
    }
    if(statusCode >= 500) {
        **if(UndertowLogger.ERROR_RESPONSE.isDebugEnabled()) {
            UndertowLogger.ERROR_RESPONSE.debugf(new RuntimeException(), "Setting error code %s for exchange %s", statusCode, this);
        }**
    }
    this.state = oldVal & ~MASK_RESPONSE_CODE | statusCode & MASK_RESPONSE_CODE;
    return this;
}
```

How do I set the log level of UndertowLogger.ERROR_RESPONSE to INFO via logback?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to create appender using logback and then you can log using slf4j Logger

Comment: What does your `logback.xml` look like?